# java GUI simple login back end mysql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm trying to create a GUI program, simple LOGIN maintenance. I have 4 gui components namely: jlabel, jtextfield, jpasswordfield and jbutton. so far, this is my code:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.*;


public class BankGui extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

// GUI components
JLabel lblUser, lblPass;
JTextField txtUser;
JPasswordField txtPass;
JButton btnOk, btnClear;

// connections to MYSQL
private static Connection connection = null;
private static Statement statement = null;
private static ResultSet resultSet = null;
//public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public void init(){
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

    lblUser = new JLabel( "Username: " );
    c.add( lblUser );
    txtUser = new JTextField( 10 );
    c.add( txtUser );

    lblPass = new JLabel( "Password:" );
    c.add( lblPass );
    txtPass = new JPasswordField( 10 );
    c.add( txtPass );

    btnOk = new JButton( "OK" );
    btnOk.addActionListener( this );
    c.add( btnOk );
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if( btnOk ){

    }
}

public void connect(){

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERS", "root", "root");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement
                .executeQuery("SELECT lname, fname FROM employees");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


}
```

But I'm stuck in the method actionperformed and my connect method. I don't know what to put there to validate if that person who logged in is an authorized user or not.

Comment: For anyone in the future, here's a simple [tutorial](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2011/10/create-login-form-using-netbeans-ide.html) on how to create a simple GUI login screen using java and mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *perform* SQL operation with `Applet` please change it to Java application (extends the *Frame/JFrame*). Read this article - [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).

You have to write `SELECT` statement with WHERE clause.

```
String sql="SELECT userName FROM employees WHERE UserName=? and Password=?";
```

EDIT:

Register the JDBC driver in `static` block

```
 static {
   try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   }catch(Exception ex) { 
       System.err.println(ex);
   }
 }
```

and write code in `actionPerformed` method:

```
PreparedStatement stmt=null;
boolean isFound=false;
try{
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERS", "root", "root");
   String sql="SELECT userName FROM employees WHERE UserName=? and Password=?";
   stmt=connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   stmt.setString(1,txtUser.getText());
   stmt.setString(2,txtPass.getPassword());             
   resultSet=stmt.executeQuery();
   if(resultSet.next()){
     isFound=true;
   }
  //     
}catch(SQLException ex){
   System.err.println(ex);
}finally{
  if(stmt!=null){
      try{ 
         stmt.close();
      }catch(Exception ex) { /* */ }
  }
 if(connection!=null){
      try{ 
         connection.close();
      }catch(Exception ex) { /* */ }
  }
}
```

Comment: am I to put that string sql in my connect method or actionperformed?

Comment: I already changed it to JFrame, how am I going to display my textfields and button?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("OK")){
                     if(connect(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText())) {
                                // Valid
                     }
                     else {
                           //Invalid
                     }

            }
        }

        public boolean connect(String usr, String pwd){

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERS", "root", "root");
                 PreparedStatement ps= connection.prepareStatement("SELECT lname, fname FROM employees where username=? and password =?");
                 ps.setString(1,usr);
                 ps.setString(2,pwd);

                resultSet = ps.executeQuery();

              if(resultSet.next()) {
                       return true;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return false;
        }
```

Comment: Be careful. You're wide open for SQL attacks without using `PrepareStatement`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I got an error in if ( btnOk ) . my btnOk is jbutton. not boolean

Comment: @Lion What am I going to do to prevent sql attacks?

Comment: You should always use parameterized query with the help of `PrepareStatement` that will prevent you SQL query from SQL injection like `SELECT lname, fname FROM employees WHERE UserName=? and Password=?`.

Comment: check above changed code, also use PrepareStatement to execute select query to get rid from SQL Injection.

Comment: Hello I followed your code, in ps.setParameter(1, usr) I got an error setParameter is undefined for the type preparedstatement

Comment: use setString instead of setParameter method

Comment: @bEtTy Barnes:) There are mapping methods with `PrepareStatement`. If the data type in the database is `int` then you can use `ps.getInt()` or `ps.setInt`. If is `varchar` then you can map it in Java using `ps.getString()` or `ps.setString()`. If it's `double` then map it using `ps.getDouble()` or `ps.setString()` and so on.

Comment: Hello, I changed my code to this: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (e.getActionCommand().equals("OK")){
                  if(connect(txtUser.getText(), txtPass.getText() ) ) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(lblValid, "Valid user!");
                  }
                  else {
                         System.out.print("Wrong password!");
                  }

         }
     }  --- but it doesn't show the JOPtionpane. I'd want to notify if the user if it is a successful login or not

Comment: try this,  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Valid User", "Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);